# How To Save/Recall Folderbrowserdialog SelectedPath

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I'm currently teaching myself (with the help of SO & Google) VB.Net to create a launcher for a multiplayer mod and I need users upon first launch of my application to input where their folder is stored, so far I have;

```
Dim folderDlg As System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg = New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    folderDlg.Description = "Please select your multiplayer folder"


    If My.Settings.isFirstRun Then
        My.Settings.isFirstRun = False
        My.Settings.Save()
        folderDlg.ShowDialog()
    Else

    End If
```

The button to run the mod itself

```
    Private Sub Launch_mp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Launch_mp.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("launcher.exe") Then
        Process.Start("launcher.exe")
        Timer2.Interval = 1000
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("eurotrucks2")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        Timer2.Stop()
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Me.Visible = True
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm confused as to how I can store the users selected path and then recall it later on for the button without always asking for the dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

You have various options where to store the information: registry, old-style using ini-files or in the config file of your application. I would suggest using the config file since you already store the isFirstRun-varialbe in the config. In project explrorer look at the "My Project" folder and double click an item called "Settings". Add a setting of type string called "ModFolder". After that you will be able to access the value of that setting using My.Settings.ModFolder varialbe (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shytyc55.aspx)).

Use the FolderBrowserDialog to store the folder (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwc80dzb.aspx))

```
if folderDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok then 
   My.Settings.ModFoler = folderDlg.SelectedPath
   My.Settings.Save
end if
```

When your application starts next time the ModFolder-variable will automaticall hold the value stored so instead of `If My.Settings.isFirstRun Then` I would check:

```
If File.Exists(Path.Combine(My.Settings.ModFolder, "AppToStart.Exe")) then
...
end if
```

If the file exists launch it, if not re-show the dialog to pick the folder.